# Scenekit how to have an X amount of rectangles at different positions?

Tags: xcode, swift

For example i have a variable named X with the value of 1, which means there would be 1 rectangle. X might become more than 1 for example 10, and 10 rectangles would appear near the first one. Now that X is 10 it might go down by for example 4 and 4 rectangles would disappear? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This example uses UIView:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768))

view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

let x = 20

for i in 0 ..< x {

    let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: 768))
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    let xPos = CGFloat(random(20, max: 1000))
    let yPos = CGFloat(random(20, max: 700))
    v.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: 30, height: 30)
    view.addSubview(v)
}
```

But you can convert it to others frameworks like SpriteKit, SceneKit.
In SceneKit just add one more dimension (z).

If you want to dinamically change the x variable and you want the view to reload you can add property observer to your x variable (didSet) and inside simple remove the old views and run the same code again.